# checking or unchecking a checkbox to move items from listview to the top or bottom

Tags: java, android, listview, checkbox

I have a listview that contains a checkbox next to each item. I want to move items to the top or bottom of the list by checking or unchecking them. If I check the item, move to the top and I uncheck, move to the bottom.

I have tried to implement different sets of code, including `setSelection(int position)`. I have been focusing on the if and else statements on the Adapter since they pertain to what happens when you check and uncheck the checkbox.  When I do try to implement the `setSelection(int position)` method, I get error messages.  Is there a way to fix the code so that `setSelection(int position)`is compatable with my code?

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<String> selectedItems;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        selectedItems = new ArrayList<String>();
        ListView chl = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.cityselector);
        chl.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        String[] items = {"Berlin", "New York", "Paris", "Mexico City", "Asana", "Tangier"};
        Adapter adapter=new Adapter(this,items);
        chl.setAdapter(adapter);

        chl.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                int item_position=i;



            }
        });

    }
```

**Adapter.java**

```
public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {

    String[] items;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
   ArrayList selectedItems;
    Activity activity;
    Adapter(Activity activity, String[] items){

        this.items=items;
        inflater=activity.getLayoutInflater();
        selectedItems = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.activity=activity;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.length;
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int i) {
        return items[i];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        View v = view;
        if(v == null){
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.checkboxlayout,null);
        }

        TextView textview_Cities=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.Textview_Cities);
        textview_Cities.setText(items[i]);

        final CheckedTextView  checkedTextView=(CheckedTextView)v.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
        checkedTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (!checkedTextView.isChecked()){
                    checkedTextView.setChecked(true);
                    selectedItems.add(items[i]);
                    //This is where I put the setSelection(int position) method////         


                }
                else {
                    checkedTextView.setChecked(false);
                    selectedItems.remove(items[i]);
                }


            }
        });



        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which error that you got?

Comment: Cannot resolve method Getselection ,( and ; expected near int, ; expected after position before the closing parenthesis.

Comment: I don't see any getSelection() method in your code. Can you please show me?

Comment: It was under the If statement in the Adapter Class.

Comment: I could not find it anywhere in your code

Comment: It was under the if statement in adapter class but I deleted it

Comment: So which error you get after delete it?

Comment: I deled it because I was getting errors- the ones I mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

You can try out this

```
 checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
                    int finalPosition = isChecked ? 0 : list.size() - 1;
                    int currentPosition = getAdapterPosition();
                    moveItem(currentPosition, finalPosition);
                }
            });



   void moveItem(int currentPosition, int finalPosition) {
            if (currentPosition < finalPosition) {
                for (int i = currentPosition; i < finalPosition; i++) {
                    Collections.swap(list, i, i + 1);
                }
            } else {
                for (int i = currentPosition; i > finalPosition; i--) {
                    Collections.swap(list, i, i - 1);
                }
            }
            notifyItemMoved(currentPosition, finalPosition);
        }
```

here the `OnCheckedChangeListener` is inside the `ViewHolder` of the `RecyclerView`.

Comment: Thanks.  Will this work if my project does not have a RecyclerView?